# How to show currently running mongod's configuration file path and db file path?

Tags: mongodb

I want to check current running `mongod`'s configurations file path and db file path, how can I achieve it by `mongo` commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do the trick ?

```
use local;
db.startup_log.find({}, { _id:0, hostname:1, startTime:1, cmdLine:1})
              .sort({startTime:-1}).limit(1)
```

Result looks like this for me (without config file in my command line) :

```
{ 
  "hostname" : "maxime", 
  "startTime" : ISODate("2015-09-29T12:10:21Z"), 
  "cmdLine" : { "storage" : { "dbPath" : "data/" } } 
}
```